# "Language Support for Java is required. Please install and enable it." -VS Code Endless loop

Tags: java, macos, visual-studio-code

In VS Code, every time I run any of my Java programs, I get [this error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N1EVF.png) at the bottom right corner. Whenever I press "install", I get prompted to [reload the window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PN7nX.png), but when I do this and try running again, it gives me the same error. Under "Java Projects" in the bottom left corner, it also says to install the Extension Pack for Java, even though I already have that installed too.

I have Java JDK 17 and all of the required extensions for VS Code, plus I've added Java to my Mac's PATH variable, but to no avail. Restarting VS Code doesn't work either. Any other suggestions?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I solved this problem uninstalling and installing again the extension and all its dependences. If you have also installed "Extension Pack for Java" then start by uninstalling that extension first.

Comment: Thanks, this solved the same problem for me!